# Winsock2 login Form c++

Tags: c++, forms, authentication, winsock, send

so i have been at this for days, im trying to connect to my own website through winsock using c++.
usually i find everything i need through google but i cannot seem to figure it out.

```
char *sendbuf = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: sn.theskatenetwork.com\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\n"
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Length: sizeofbody\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflat\r\n"
    "Keep-Alive: 30\r\n"
    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "---------------------------7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ID\"; text=\"testing\"\r\n"
    "-----------------------------7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "---------------------------7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Password\"; text=\"testing\"\r\n"
    "-----------------------------7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "\r\n";
```

I am not too sure if i am sending the input right as everything i have seen only consists of sending files. 
I also cannot figure out how to check cookies to see if i have been logged in. I am assuming that in order to do that I've got to send again as a get but that's about all i know. 
It seems as if most people only use vb to write winsock but that is not an option right now.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this manually, instead of using an existing API/library? Microsoft has WinINET and WinHTTP APIs, for instance. Or use libcurl, or any number of other libraries. HTTP is a complex protocol to implement by hand.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I rather learn it the hard way. I like challenges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it does not work is because your MIME body data is malformed:

1. you are not using dashes correctly for the boundaries in between each MIME part.  If you get rid of (or at least reduce) the dashes in your boundary, this is easier to see.
2. your text values inside of each MIME part is not formatted correctly.  The `Content-Disposition` header does not have a `text` attribute.  You need to move the text to the MIME part's body, and you need to separate the MIME part's headers and body with a blank line, similar to the separation of the main HTTP message's headers and body.

Try this instead:

```
char *sendbuf = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: sn.theskatenetwork.com\r\n"
    "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\n"
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 167\r\n"
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
    "Keep-Alive: 30\r\n"
    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "--7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ID\"\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "testing\r\n"
    "--7dd37b37e06e2\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Password\"\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "testing\r\n"
    "--7dd37b37e06e2--\r\n";
```

Or more C++ like:

```
std::string host = "sn.theskatenetwork.com";
std::string boundary = "7dd37b37e06e2";
std::string id = "testing";
std::string psw = "testing";

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "--" << boundary << "\r\n"
       "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ID\"\r\n"
       "\r\n"
       << id << "\r\n"
       "--" << boundary << "\r\n"
       "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Password\"\r\n"
       "\r\n"
       << psw << "\r\n"
       "--" << boundary << "--\r\n";

std::string senddata = oss.str();

oss.str("");
oss.clear();

oss << "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
       "Host: " << host << "\r\n"
       "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml\r\n"
       "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" << boundary << "\r\n"
       "Content-Length: " << senddata.size() << "\r\n"
       "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
       "Keep-Alive: 30\r\n"
       "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
       "\r\n"
       << senddata;

std::string sendbuf = oss.str();

// use sendbuf.c_str() and sendbuf.size() as needed...
```

Read RFCs [2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045), [2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046), [2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047), [2048](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2048), and [2049](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) for the official MIME spec.

Read W3C's HTML specs ([HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#multipart-form-data)), as well as [RFC 2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388), for how to format `multipart/form-data` data.

As for cookies, they are sent to you in an HTTP response, and you send them back in subsequent requests to the same server/path.  Read [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) for the official cookie spec.

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate it. now im getting further. except for a 501 server not implemented, GET to index.html not supported. 
i understand that. the index page is not meant to take inputs. ive changed my header to "POST \member.php HTTP/1.1\r\n" and still get the error. ill continue to google.
Turns out i am successfully logged in though.